# Multiple column names/custom label in Rails collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `form_for` in Rails that uses the `collection_check_boxes` method for an array of parts that get listed as check boxes. I want the label of the checkbox to be a composite of two methods so that each part's checkbox is labeled with it's name and it's SKU number:

my form code:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:service, :part_ids, @parts_list, :id, :sku, {}, {checked: true}) %>
```

this works perfectly to create a list of check boxes. But each label is only the `:sku` since I can only pass it one method for the label. Does anyone know of a way to create a custom label for these? I have read the api docs and it mentions using a `do |b| ... end` block but doesn't explain how to use it or why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the modified form code:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:service, :part_ids, @parts_list, :id, :sku, {}, {checked: true}) do |b| 
  b.label { b.check_box + b.object.name + " " + b.object.sku} 
end %>
```

**NOTE:** 
`b.object.name`  #### Assuming that `name` is field name in your model
`b.object.sku`   #### Replace with `b.object.sku.to_s` if `sku` is numeric field.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a custom field in your model:

```
def cb_label
    "#{name} #{sku}"
end
```

and in the collection

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:service, :part_ids, @parts_list, :id, :cb_label, {}, {checked: true}) %>
```

Comment: Kirti's answer is the correct one for my question, though before I got an answer I thought to try the alias method above and it also works just fine. If I was calling the name/sku combo in a lot of different places I would use your answer because it is easier. Thus the up vote.